# Xcode 7 GM Build breaks cast from NSArray to Swift Array

Tags: nsarray, swift2, xcode7

Just downloaded the Xcode 7 GM build and my project is seeing the following runtime error:

```
NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

We see this in a number of places, probably the simples example is this:

```
var cacheDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
```

However it happens in other places where Array casts had previously succeeded.

This code runs fine using Xcode7-beta6.

This code also runs fine when starting a fresh project with Xcode.

This code also runs fine when the debugger is not attached...

Any ideas?

Stack Trace below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we never were able to get to the bottom of this. It seemed as though there was some build setting in our project at was causing all kinds of strange errors similar to the one above when using the Xcode7 GM build. We ultimately had to copy all our files into a new project to work around it.